# VMWare player and Windows 7 network problem

Tags: windows-7, networking, debian, vmware-player

Sorry, but I have no idea about Windows, since I'm not really interested (I always use Linux), but at my work, I have to use it, so it's the rule.

My problem is with VMware and a network issue.

**Scenario**

- I have a laptop with Windows 7. Here is my network configuration (the IP address is fixed):

  - IP: `192.168.1.236`
  - Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
  - Default gateway: `192.168.1.1`
  - DNS: `192.168.1.113`
- I have the VMware Player network adapter defined as follows, maybe that's wrong? I just configured the IP address and subnet mask:

  - IP: `192.168.1.1`
  - Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- I have a Debian installation under VMware and I've set up the network with another fixed IP address that was assigned to me to by the network administrator:

  - IP: `192.168.1.238`
  - Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
  - Default gateway: `192.168.1.1`
  - DNS: `192.168.1.113`
  - Broadcast IP: `192.168.1.255`

**What I'm trying to do**

- I want to give the Debian virtual machine access to the Internet
- I want that virtual machine to be visible in the network to others as if it was another common server

**My problem**

- When I set up the VMware virtual machine with NAT, my virtual server can be seen in the network with the assigned IP but can't reach the Internet.
- When I set up the VMware virtual machine in bridge or host only I can reach the Internet from the virtual machine, but it can't be seen on my network by another computer.

I'm sure that I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea. Could you help me, please?

Comment: It should be in Bridge mode. Not sure why you wouldn't be able to access via a local machine. Try setting the eth0 to grab an IP from your DHCP server and make sure it's in bridge mode. Reboot the VMWare instance and see if that works. Usually I give it a reboot if I change the network adapter settings since Repair often takes as long as a reboot.

Comment: The problem with what you are talking about is the the ip assigned to my virtual server must be fixed, it is assigned by the network admin, and nothing about dhcp, I was wondering if there's something wrong with the vmware network adapter I have configured into the windows vista, maybe, I don't know...

Comment: Try dynamic first to make sure that you have things set up properly. Worry about static once you get it working.

Comment: @Sathya, did you see my edit?  How should I have edited this question?

Comment: @DragonLord a little too late.. our edits collided, Sorry.

Comment: nothing wrong with the interface adaptor?

Comment: I have not idea, and I'm in a hurry, please help.

Comment: @Sathya, I figured there was an edit conflict...  What should be done?

Comment: @DragonLord I don't think anything needs to be done.. you're free to rollback changes to yours if you feel so